# Slow recompilaton times in big project

Tags: angular

I have quite big `angular@11` project. `App` folder has 4MB within 2100 files. I know it is big.
Initial compliation takes over 130 seconds.
My command is `node --max_old_space_size=10000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve` so I'm giving node extra memory.

Problem is with recompilation. I've made an isolated lazy loaded module:

```
{
    path: 'dev',
    loadChildren: () => import('@dev/dev-pages/dev-pages.module').then(m => m.DevPagesModule)
  },
```

In that module I have only one, auto generated page component:

```
<p>page-dev-test works!</p>
```

If I add any string to template it takes almost 20 seconds to recompile (file is only 7kB) :/ Is it normal? Can I speed this up?
[image]

Comment: If you are using angular 11 you can enable hot module replacement by setting --hmr flag ng serve --hmr https://angular.io/cli/serve

Comment: I tried - no changes in recompilation times

Comment: if HMR enabled it will show HMR enabled warning. in your screenshot it''s not there?

Comment: I know - tried that earlier. I'll try again

Comment: With HMR also 20 seconds form recompilation :/